# How many digits does the number $3.00435\times 10^9+0.00002 \times 10^{-53}$ have?

Tags: arithmetic

How many digits does the number  $$3.00435\cdot10^9+0.00002\cdot10^{-53}$$ have? Can anyone help to find this? Thanks

Comment: Any thought about this question?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Multiplying by $10$ moves the decimal point one place to the right; multiplying by $10^{-1}$ moves it one place to the left. Thus,

$$3.00435\cdot10^9=3004350000$$

and

$$0.00002\cdot10^{-53}=0.\underbrace{00\ldots00}_{53\text{ zeroes}}00002\;.$$

If you think about it for a moment, it’s not hard to count the digits in the sum.

Answer (score 0):

The first number 3.00435×10^9 has 10 digits. The second number is equal to 2×10^(-58) which has 58 digits. Hence a total of 68 digits.

Comment: By that line of reasoning, I could say *"$1$ has one digit, $10$ has two digits, hence $1 + 10$ should have a total of $3$ digits"*.  A bit more explanation is needed here.

Comment: What I meant was when we add a whole number and a decimal number like the one asked i.e 0.0000...2 where there are 57 zeroes the total no.of digits are 10+58=68

Comment: Then that's what you should say.  Giving answers in a precise and clear fashion is hard, but is a part of answering questions